# Safely store SMTP password in a Docker node.JS project

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, security, encryption

I need to store a encrypted password, that is needed in runtime (a SMTP password).

The problem i am facing is that I also need to store a key to decrypt the password again, what ways could this be solved? Since if the key is stored along side with the encrypted password it would be the same as having it in plain text.

Its a customer demand, so in case their server gets hacked the hacker wont have direct access to all their passwords.

The software in making is coded in NodeJS and are running in a Docker container.

A solution that I thought about was to store the encryption key in another file, at another location in the Docker instance but this doesn't seem very secure either.

Thanks in advance

*edit, not sure if my question wasn't understood. But what I meant to ask if there was a secure way to do this or not, and if there is where should I look for more info about it.*

Comment: I need to make sure that 2==3. It is a customer demand. What should I do?

Comment: I am sorry if my question has offended you, but I came to stackoverflow to see if there was a possible solution to this and not to be mocked.

Comment: You should have some minimal background in computer security before doing any security related work for a real customer. If you have accepted this job you should be able to answer this question better than anyone else. Of course you can't do what your customer wants. It *is* a 2==3 question. Sorry if this offends you.

Comment: Hello again, sorry if I was kind of a dick. I thought the same (it isnt possible to do), but then thought that there might be a solution I didn't know about, thanks for taking your time though :)

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me, I sometimes can be a dick too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you should use plain text password in run time, there is no way to secure your passwords from hacking the server. Same problem is exist about database credential. If you store encryption key any where, one function in your code  decrypt the encrypted password for using in run time, so hacker can use that function to find plain text passwords

Comment: Thank you, that's also what I came to conclusion about. Just needed it confirmed.